# How to configure Server.MapPath correctly?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, itext

I'm using Itextsharp, but I have issues retrieving an image.

I'm using

```c
iTextSharp.text.Image Logo2 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("Images") + "/Logo.png");
```

But I'm not getting the expected result. The path I need, should be `d:\webs\site\images` but `Server.MapPath()` returns `d:\webs\images`. The `site` folder is missing, and this (obviously) results in an error when trying to create the `Image` with iTextSharp.

How do I get `MapPath` to return the path I need?

Comment: I edited the question because it was phrased as a problem caused by iTextSharp. It wasn't: the problem is caused by passing the wrong path to iTextSharp.

Comment: Further re-tagged to ASP.Net. As Bruno said, the question is really "How do I use Server.MapPath() correctly?"